# apply css to ms word

Tags: html, css, ms-word

Currently, I'm importing an HTML file (with a linked CSS stylesheet) into my WINWORD application. Certain things like `h1` seem to work somewhat while other behave differently.

this is my HTML (simplified and sensitive data replaced):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2S Draft//EN"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>myTitle</title>
<meta name="Generator" content="myContent">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://someURL/documentStyles.css">

<base target="BODY"> 
</head>

<body class='contents' topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
<h1>myTitle</h1>
<p class="classThatWorks">my first content</p>
<p class="classThatDoesNotWork">my second content</p>
</body>
```

and my CSS:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #1075BD;
    margin-bottom: 6pt;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 36pt;
    line-height: 46pt;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.classThatWorks {
    font-size: 8pt;
    line-height: 10pt;
    margin-top: 4pt;
}

.classThatDoesNotWork {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #747474;
    font-size: 9pt;
    line-height: 13pt;
}
```

I import the HTML file via VBA:

```
Sub fetchSource()
    Selection.InsertFile _
        FileName:="MYPATH", _
        Range:="", _
        ConfirmConversions:=False, _
        Link:=False, _
        Attachment:=False
End Sub
```

What happens is that the `font-size` gets applied for `h1` and the working class, but not the not-working class. Same for the `color` attribute. `font-family` on the other hand seems to not work on any of these elements at all.

How can I get Word to recognize ALL of the given styles by the CSS file on all the specified elements.

Comment: Word basically doesn't support HTML. It uses an internal, non-documented converter to import HTML "as best it can", but full compatibility is not guaranteed. The converter dates more from the earlier days of HTML (1990's). Some things it recognizes, others it doesn't. `font-family` is not a concept used in Word, only font names, so it's not surprising that's not recognized. H1 is correlated with Word's "Heading 1" style, so it probably picks up information from that with less problems.

Comment: All-in-all, however, this is not a programming question and were better asked in an end-user venue where you're more likely to find people who do this kind of thing on a regular basis.